# Sql Server 2008 Join Three tables without having result duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently trying to write a query in SQL Server 2008 to Join Four tables without having the results duplicate. Here are the four tables I'm trying to join...

```
From Financials AS FIN --(Has Only One Row Per Company)
left join FinancialDetail AS FINDTL --(Has Multple Rows Per Company)
left join FinancialDiag AS FINDI --(Has Multple Rows Per Company)
left join FinancialPr AS FINPR --(Has Multple Rows Per Company)
```

The Three tables (FinancialDetail,FinancialDiag,FinancialPr)  are never same number of rows between each other. One Table could have 3 and the other could have 10 etc.
The only column i have to link them on are ID-NO which is unique for each Company.

I tried a union all which works but im hoping i can somehow try to collapse the rows to bring everything together.

i tried was creating a rank column and only had the first row as number 1 then linking the tables by the first row number. 
This only collapsed one row so its no exactly what i want but closer to what i'm looking to do.

Any advice would be great on how i could go about this...if this is possible.

Here's my Union query. I'll paste my results at the end....

```
DECLARE @IDNO BIGINT

SET @IDNO = 10077110620

   SELECT 

   "ID NO"                      = FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO],
   "FIN REG"                    = FIN.[PA-FIN-REG],
   "FINDI CD"                   = FINDI.[PA-FIN-DI-CODE],
   "FINPR CD"                   = '',
   "FINPR MOD"                  = '',
   "FINDTL CD"                  = '',
   "FINDTL DES"                 = ''

   FROM
        dbo.Financials AS FIN 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FinancialDiag AS FINDI ON
        FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO]=FINDI.[PA-FIN-ID-NO]


   WHERE 
        FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = ''+@IDNO+''

UNION ALL


   SELECT 

   "ID NO"                      = '',
   "FIN REG"                    = '',
   "FINDI CD"                   = '',
   "FINPR CD"                   = FINPR.[PA-FIN-PR-CD],
   "FINPR MOD"                  = FINPR.[PA-FIN-CD-MOD],
   "FINDTL CD"                  = '',
   "FINDTL DES"                 = ''

   FROM
        dbo.FinancialPr AS FINPR


   WHERE 
        FINPR.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = ''+@IDNO+''

UNION ALL

  SELECT

   "ID NO"                      = '',
   "FIN REG"                    = '',
   "FINDI CD"                   = '',
   "FINPR CD"                   = '',
   "FINPR MOD"                  = '',
   "FINDTL CD"                  = FINDTL.[PA-FIN-DTL-CD],
   "FINDTL DES"                 = FINDTL.[PA-FIN-DTL-DESC]


  FROM
      dbo.FinancialDetail AS FINDTL

  WHERE 
      FINDTL.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = ''+@IDNO+''
```

Results :

```
[ID NO]       [FIN REG]    [FINDI CD]  [FINPR CD] [FINPR MOD]  [FINDTL CD][FINDTL DES]

411143356205    786.59      786.59                  
411143356205    786.59      786.50                  
411143356205    786.59      765.1                   
411143356205    786.59      786.05                  
411143356205    786.59      451.9                   
411143356205    786.59      300.00                  
411143356205    786.59      V68                     
411143356205    786.59      354.0                   
411143356205    786.59      177.9                   
411143356205    786.59      321.1                   
411143356205    786.59      V68.0                   
411143356205    786.59      V47.3                   
411143356205    786.59      726.50                  
411143356205    786.59      712.0                   
                                         790.0       T  
                                                                 G7898      DES1
                                                                85550       DES2
                                                                83437       DES3
                                                                85670       DES4
                                                                87890       DES5
                                                                81213       DES6
                                                                81454       DES7
```

This is how i would like it to look...

```
 [ID NO]      [FIN REG] [FINDI CD]        [FINPR CD] [FINPR MOD][FINDTL CD] [FINDTL DES]

411143356205    786.59      786.59            790.0       T        G7898        DES1
411143356205    786.59      786.50                                 85550        DES2
411143356205    786.59      765.1                                  83437        DES3
411143356205    786.59      786.05                                 85670        DES4
411143356205    786.59      451.9                                  87890        DES5
411143356205    786.59      300.00                                 81213        DES6
411143356205    786.59      V68                                    81454        DES7
411143356205    786.59      354.0                   
411143356205    786.59      177.9                   
411143356205    786.59      321.1                   
411143356205    786.59      V68.0                   
411143356205    786.59      V47.3                   
411143356205    786.59      726.50                  
411143356205    786.59      712.0
```

Comment: When you want "no duplicates", do you want (first,last,biggest,smallest) row from the FinancialDetail table or will any random row do?

Comment: Can you use `DISTINCT`?  Otherwise what about some sort of subquery in the joins, like

`left join FinancialDetail AS FINDTL on FINDTL.ID = FIN.FINDTLID
AND FINDTL.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM FinancialDetail f WHERE f.ID = FINDTL.ID)`

Comment: I'm unable to use distinct unless i do a count for columns that have 2 or more cds. i need each record or at least need to know how many times        FINDI.[PA-FIN-DI-CODE],FINPR.[PA-FIN-PR-CD],FINDTL.[PA-FIN-DTL-CD] appears . I also just tried numbering each row in every table but ran into the issue where some table have more row than others and its never always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you are looking for is not relational.  You can build that table by doing repeated inserts from each of the tables into a temp table with a row_number() clause, then select all of the rows, group by the row number column, and take the max of every field other than the ID NO.  For example:

```
DECLARE @IDNO BIGINT

SET @IDNO = 10077110620

DECLARE @results AS TABLE (
    -- TODO: uncomment and define your columns here
    -- [FINDI CD]
    --, [FINPR CD]
    --, [FINPR MOD]
    --, [FINDTL CD]
    --, [FINDTL DES]
    , rownum int
)

INSERT INTO @results([FINDI CD], rownum)
SELECT 
   FINDI.[PA-FIN-DI-CODE]
 , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) -- TODO: define a better ordering
FROM dbo.FinancialDiag AS FINDI
WHERE FINDI.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = @IDNO

INSERT INTO @results([FINPR CD], [FINPR MOD], rownum)
SELECT 
   FINPR.[PA-FIN-PR-CD]
 , FINPR.[PA-FIN-CD-MOD]
 , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) -- TODO: define a better ordering
FROM dbo.FinancialPr AS FINPR
WHERE FINPR.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = @IDNO

INSERT INTO @results([FINDTL CD], [FINDTL DES], rownum)
SELECT 
   FINDTL.[PA-FIN-DTL-CD]
 , FINDTL.[PA-FIN-DTL-DESC]
 , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) -- TODO: define a better ordering
FROM dbo.FinancialDetail AS FINDTL
WHERE FINDTL.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = @IDNO

SELECT 
 , "ID NO"      = FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO]
 , "FIN REG"    = FIN.[PA-FIN-REG]
 , "FINDI CD"   = ISNULL(sq.[FINDI CD], '')
 , "FINPR CD"   = ISNULL(sq.[FINPR CD], '')
 , "FINPR MOD"  = ISNULL(sq.[FINPR MOD], '')
 , "FINDTL CD"  = ISNULL(sq.[FINDTL CD], '')
 , "FINDTL DES" = ISNULL(sq.[FINDTL DES], '')
FROM dbo.Financials AS FIN
 , (
    SELECT
       rownum
     , "FINDI CD"   = MAX(r.[FINDI CD])
     , "FINPR CD"   = MAX(r.[FINPR CD])
     , "FINPR MOD"  = MAX(r.[FINPR MOD])
     , "FINDTL CD"  = MAX(r.[FINDTL CD])
     , "FINDTL DES" = MAX(r.[FINDTL DES])
    FROM @results r
    GROUP BY rownum
   ) AS sq
WHERE FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = @IDNO
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. This is exactly what i needed. So your dropping the data to temp table while creating a row_number() for each row. I'm still trying to grasp how your able to join tables if one table have more rows than the other. I'm going to keep breaking it down to see if  i can fully understand. how your linking the null rows.

Comment: is there anyway i can use this query and qualify on multiple ID NO. So instead of         FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = @IDNO       i want to use     FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] IN (10077110620,12344110620). At the moment abelt o get the correct row number to the ID NO using....    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  (select [PA-FIN-ID-NO]) ORDER BY [PA-FIN-ID-NO]) as the rownum, but i can't seem to link the results to the correct ID NO. The results get mixed with each other. any tips on what i would need to do would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the row numbering using the partition, as you already are.  Store the [PA-FIN-ID-NO] value in @results for each of the inserts.  Then change the final query to group by both [PA-FIN-ID-NO] and rownum, and join back FIN on [PA-FIN-ID-NO].

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO]
, FIN.[PA-FIN-REG]
, (SELECT TOP 1 FINDI.[PA-FIN-DI-CODE] FROM FinancialDiag AS FINDI WHERE FINDI.[PA-FIN-ID-NO] = FIN.[PA-FIN-ID-NO]) AS [PA-FIN-DI-CODE]
...
From Financials AS FIN --(Has Only One Row Per Company)
```

Comment: The thing is i need to see every record or at least a count if there is more than 1 of the same code.

Comment: How can you see every record without seeing every record? As in: you can not see every record and get only one record per company.

Comment: by record i mean if the one company has more than one code in either of the table (FinancialDetail, FinancialDiag,FinancialPr)